# rspec Let() behavior in helper specs

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, tdd, rspec-rails

I have the following in my `application_helper_spec.rb`

```
shared_examples_for "some shared process" do

    it "displays the value defined by Let" do
        puts object.inspect # This should output the value defined by Let
    end

end

describe ApplicationHelper do

    describe "a_helper_methond" do

        describe "some behaviour" do
            let(:object) { "foo" }
            puts object.inspect # This should output the value defined by Let
            it_should_behave_like "some shared process"
        end

    end

end
```

However, when I run this I get two errors on both puts:

```
undefined local variable or method `object' for #<Class:0x007f951a3a7b20> (NameError)
```

Why? I have the exact same code in my model and request specs at it runs fine, but in the helper specs it doesn't.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `let` call defines a method in the context your specs will be executed. Your `puts` statement however is outside that scope. You need to wrap it inside an `it` block.

```
it 'print debug output' do
  puts object.inspect
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I also further improved this by putting the Let command inside the it_behaves_like block